# Слушатель на BooleanProperty

Tags: java, javafx

Добрый день

Есть список объектов BooleanProperty, в который время от времени добавляются новые объекты (отрезки времени не одинаковые), изначально все эти объекты инициализированы со значением true. Так же в процессе работы программы у некоторых объектов из этого списка значение меняется на false (отрезки времени не одинаковые). Доступа к методу который меняет данное значение нет, то есть можно только слушать объекты списка. Heобходимо, что бы после изменения объекта, он удалялся из данного списка, а его индекс передавался в некоторый метод. Написал упрощенное решение того что нужно, но все работает как-то не так. При первом изменении удаления не происходит, при втором изменении удаляется объект с индексом 1, далее получаем исключение IndexOutOfBoundsException

```
 package example;

 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;
 import java.util.logging.Level;
 import java.util.logging.Logger;
 import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
 import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;

 public class Main {
     private static final List<BooleanProperty> LIST = new ArrayList<>();

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         fillList(3);
         change(3);                
    }

private static void fillList(int count) {
    for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
        int time = (int) (Math.random() * 10000 + 1000);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(time);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        LIST.add(new SimpleBooleanProperty(true));
    }


}

private static void change(int count) {
    for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
        int time = (int) (Math.random() * 10000 + 1000);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(time);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        switch (i + 1) {
            case 1:
                LIST.get(i).set(false);
                listner();
                break;
            case 2:
                LIST.get(i).set(false);
                listner();
                break;
            case 3:
                LIST.get(i).set(false);
                listner();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

private static void listner() {
    for (int i=0; i<LIST.size(); i++) {
        int step = i;
        LIST.get(i).addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (!newValue) {
                LIST.get(step).set(true);
                doSomething(step);
                LIST.remove(step);
            }
        });    
    }
}

private static void doSomething(int step) {
    System.out.println("step: " + step);
}
```

}

Comment: Исключение IndexOutOfBoundsException получаете потому, что на третьей итерации в `change()` пытаетесь удалить элемент с индексом 2, а в коллекции остался только один элемент (первый и второй уже удалены).

Comment: Немного подкорректирую: к третьей итерации у вас остается два элемента (так как первый не удалился из за того, что слушатели добавляются только в конце первой итерации), но индекс 2 и в этом случае - "мимо".

Comment: Я понимаю, что там ошибка, но не знаю, как исправить

Comment: Можно поставить `listner();` сразу после `fillList(3);` И убрать все вызовы `listner();` из `change()`. И "перевернуть" цикл в `change()`.

Comment: И если не хотите вручную ставить слушателей каждый раз, когда кто-то добавляет в коллекцию, то смотрите мой ответ ниже.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В классе `javafx.collections.FXCollections` есть пара статических методов, создающих обертки и отличающихся от других наличием параметра `extractor`:

```
static <E> ObservableList<E> observableArrayList(Callback<E,Observable[]> extractor)
static <E> ObservableList<E> observableList(List<E> list, Callback<E,Observable[]> extractor)
```

Используя первый метод получаем:

```
package example;

import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

public class Main {
    private static final ObservableList<BooleanProperty> LIST =
            FXCollections.observableArrayList(p -> new Observable[]{p});

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LIST.addListener(new ListChangeListener<BooleanProperty>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Change<? extends BooleanProperty> c) {
                while (c.next()) {
                    // Чтобы посмотреть изменения:
                    if (c.wasPermutated()) {
                        for (int i = c.getFrom(); i < c.getTo(); ++i) {
                            System.out.println("Permuted: " + i + " " + LIST.get(i));
                        }
                    } else if (c.wasUpdated()) {
                        for (int i = c.getFrom(); i < c.getTo(); ++i) {
                            System.out.println("Updated: " + i + " " + LIST.get(i));
                        }
                    } else {
                        for (BooleanProperty removedItem : c.getRemoved()) {
                            System.out.println("Removed: " + removedItem);
                        }
                        for (BooleanProperty addedItem : c.getAddedSubList()) {
                            System.out.println("Added: " + addedItem);
                        }
                    }

                    // Полезная нагрузка:    
                    for (int step = c.getFrom(); step < c.getTo(); ++step) {
                        if (!LIST.get(step).get()) {
                            LIST.get(step).set(true);
                            doSomething(step);
                            LIST.remove(step);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        fillList(3);
        change(3);
    }

    private static void fillList(int count) {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
//            int time = (int) (Math.random() * 10000 + 1000);
//            try {
//                Thread.sleep(time);
//            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
//                Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
//            }

            LIST.add(new SimpleBooleanProperty(true));
        }


    }

    private static void change(int count) {
        for (int i = count - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
//            int time = (int) (Math.random() * 10000 + 1000);
//            try {
//                Thread.sleep(time);
//            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
//                Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
//            }

            switch (i + 1) {
                case 1:
                    LIST.get(i).set(false);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    LIST.get(i).set(false);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    LIST.get(i).set(false);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void doSomething(int step) {
        System.out.println("step: " + step);
    }

}
```

Слушатель устанавливается до внесения изменений (сразу в `main()`), так как он в прошлое не может послушать.

Вызовы `Thread.sleep()` закомментированны, потому что в этом примере только один поток - хоть сколько жди, а "race condition" не дождешься.

Comment: Thread.sleep() я добавил, чтобы было понятно, что через разные промежутки времени добавляются и изменяются, так он конечно не нужен.
Спасибо, все получилось.

Answer (score 1):

Если я вас правильно понял, то....

Создаем wrapper для коллекции

```
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class BooleanPropertyCollection {
private List<BooleanProperty> listBooleanProperty = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Event> listener = new ArrayList<>();

public void add(SimpleBooleanProperty item) {
    listBooleanProperty.add(item);
}
//Публичный лишь для примера, в вашем случае, как я вас понял, он будет private
public void change(int index, boolean newValue) {
    listBooleanProperty.set(index, new SimpleBooleanProperty(newValue));
    for (Event event: listener) {
        event.onChange(this,index);
    }
}

public void remove(int index){
    listBooleanProperty.remove(index);
}

public int getSize(){
    return listBooleanProperty.size();
}

public BooleanProperty getElementByIndex(int index){
    return listBooleanProperty.get(index);
}

public void subscribeOnChange(Event event) {
    listener.add(event);
}
}
```

Создадим `iterface Event`

```
public interface Event {
public void onChange(BooleanPropertyCollection booleanPropertyCollection, int index);
}
```

И пример использования:

```
BooleanPropertyCollection test =  new BooleanPropertyCollection();
    test.subscribeOnChange((BooleanPropertyCollection booleanPropertyCollection, int index) -> {
        System.out.println("Размер до: "+booleanPropertyCollection.getSize());
        System.out.println("Изменился элемент index: "+index);
        booleanPropertyCollection.remove(index);
        System.out.println("Удалили элемент с index: "+index);
        System.out.println("Размер после: "+booleanPropertyCollection.getSize());
    });
    test.add(new SimpleBooleanProperty(false));
    test.add(new SimpleBooleanProperty(true));
    test.change(1,true);
```

Comment: Оказалось, что все равно проблема осталась. В данном случае в методе change заменяется сам объект listBooleanProperty.set(index, new SimpleBooleanProperty(newValue));, мне же надо, что бы менялось только значение объекта. В итоге мне надо так в классе BooleanPropertyCollection добавим список private final List<BooleanProperty> actonList = new ArrayList<>(); Соответственно изменится метод add public void add(BooleanProperty item) {
        listBooleanProperty.add(item);
        actonList.add(item);
    } Далее изменение значения происходит в actonList, а так как в обоих списках лежат ссылки

Comment: То необходимо, чтобы BooleanPropertyCollection реагировал на изменение значения в другом месте public void change(int index, boolean newValue) {
        actonList.get(index).set(newValue);
    }
Но так не срабатывает